# When is the branch name updated?

Tags: git

I'm reading John Wiegley's [Git from the bottom up](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/). In [Introduction](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/)
he mentioned:

> If you checkout a branch, `HEAD` symbolically refers to that branch,
> indicating that the branch name should be updated after the next commit operation.

I'm confused here: for example `master` is a (special) branch name, it's always `master` isn't it? When will it be changed after a commit?

Comment: `master` is just the [default branch name](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell): "The “master” branch in Git is not a special branch. It is exactly like any other branch. The only reason nearly every repository has one is that the git init command creates it by default and most people don’t bother to change it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the context, it means that the commit referenced by the branch will be changed from the current to the next created commit. The current commit is the parent (or one of the parents) of the newly created one. It's not the branch name itself that will be changed.

Comment: ok now i'm clear about the concept. thank you!